# How to perform data scaling/standardization on dataset containing grouped values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-cleaning, feature-engineering

I have a dataset containing the results of executing problem instances with different given solver strategies. Simplified example:

```
| Problem_instance | Problem_Size | Used_Solver | Cost |
| P1               |           50 | A           |   75 |
| P1               |           50 | B           |  125 |
| P1               |           50 | C           |  225 |
| P1               |           50 | D           |  100 |
| P2               |          150 | A           |  165 |
| P2               |          150 | B           |  360 |
| P2               |          150 | C           |  275 |
| P2               |          150 | D           |   45 |
| P3               |           25 | A           |   35 |
| P3               |           25 | B           |   65 |
| ...              |          ... | ...         |  ... |
```

I'm trying to use machine learning to predict the best performing Solver for a given problem instance. In data processing stage, I need to standardize or scale my data, but I'm not sure how to this best.

Firstly, I'm not sure which sklearn Scaler to use (StandardScalar/ MinMaxScaler/..).

Secondly, I'm confused how to handle the different records for each instance. When I group the data first based on problem_instance and then use a MinMaxScaler, the record with Cost = 0 would be the best solution for this problem and Cost=1 the worst. But if I use the same strategy to scale the Problem_Size this would be equal to 0 everywhere. On the other hand if I use a global scaling, the information about which Solver is the best for each instance is lost.

Can someone help me how to handle the data preprocessing for this problem?

Comment: It looks like your stackoverflow question is made of multiple subquestions. It is better to split these questions in to multiple stackoverflow questions. This will help others help you best.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to scale the Problem_Size columns with MinMaxScaler since as you stated those values are groupped by Problem_instance. As for Cost one might use the MinMaxScaler.

Comment: and should I perform te scaling also grouped per problem_instance, or should do it over the full dataset?

Comment: Perform the scaling over the full dataset.